# JsonMappingException for Spring RestTemplate json post

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to post a json like {"username":"mike", "password":"123"} with RestTemplate. Response will be nothing but HTTP 200.

When I post with curl, it works, but with RestTemplate it shows  -

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class model.User] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method`

```
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<String>(jsonString, httpHeaders), String.class);
```

I produce my "jsonString" with Jackson and Gson, it looks identical to shown above.
(Spring 3.2.2, jackson mapper and asl 1.9.3)

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does your `User` class look like?

Comment: @Sotirios: Simple pojo. But if pojo have problem then curl request should have failed.